when I try to build android on expo with aar file, I get error called :react-native-akamaibmp:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar?



when I try to build android on expo with aar file, I get error called
:react-native-akamaibmp:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar?
ERROR :
Task :react-native-akamaibmp:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :react-native-akamaibmp project caused this error
Does anyone has a solution for this?
